# SQL how to use condition on multiple column as one

Tags: mysql, laravel

My Table is

[image: product_property table whe i store all product property]

```
product_uuid                          key_name      key_value
95be9cf4-7121-492b-8725-762e6353ac51  categories    Starter
95be9cf4-7121-492b-8725-762e6353ac51  print_order   1
95be9cf4-7121-492b-8725-762e6353ac51  available     1
95be9cf4-7121-492b-8725-762e6353ac52  categories    Starter
95be9cf4-7121-492b-8725-762e6353ac52  print_order   2
95be9cf4-7121-492b-8725-762e6353ac52  available     1
```

Here i want to query all the product uuid which has category "Starter" and which has print_order "1" and available "1".

"?categories=Starter&print_order=1"

I Tried something like

```
$request = [
  "categories": "Starter",
  "print_order": "1"
]


$p = DB::table('product_properties');
foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
    if($key === 'provider_uuid') {
       continue;
    }
    $p->Where([['key_name', '=', $key], ['key_value', '=', $value]]);
}
return $p->get();
```

But it doesnot gives the result

My Expected Result is

```
product_uuid
95be9cf4-7121-492b-8725-762e6353ac51
```

Comment: Post your data sample as text!

Comment: And the expected result ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha Thank you. My expected results are the product_uuids, I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT product_uuid
FROM tablename
WHERE (key_name, key_value) IN ( ('categories' , 'Starter'),
                                 ('print_order', '1'      ),
                                 ('available'  , '1'      ) )
GROUP BY product_uuid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT key_name) = 3
```

Comment: Thank you.

But it is not executing

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT key_name) = 3 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 7"

Comment: are you sure, @Akina, that OP looked for an SQL statement?

Comment: @hasanmuntasir #1 - You have tagged your question as [mysql]-relative whereas your DBMS is MariaDB. #2 - MariaDB supports [COUNT(DISTINCT)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/count-distinct/). Search your code for misprint (for example, for a space between function name and parenthesis). #3 - You have edited my query - hence you'd provide **your** SQL code while reporting about error.

Comment: @hasanmuntasir The query works fine in `MySQL` and `MariaDB` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=2bb9f1dc46305284789cac24d87cb4a7

Comment: @cyberbrain Converting SQL to framework code is 2nd step in task solving. Which needs in separate question, I think...

Comment: @Akina My apologies. its solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

You could join the same table three times with the different condition from each join :

```
select t1.product_uuid
from test_tbl t1 
inner join test_tbl t2 on t1.product_uuid=t2.product_uuid
inner join test_tbl t3 on t1.product_uuid=t3.product_uuid
where t1.key_name='categories' and t1.key_value='Starter'
and t2.key_name='print_order' and t2.key_value='1'
and t3.key_name='available' and t3.key_value='1';
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> product_uuid
> 95be9cf4-7121-492b-8725-762e6353ac51
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4b558dafd9a4ac03afc57e3b1772215)